# Spring Boot application not starting on Tomcat external server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have an application made with Spring Boot 2.5.7 and we are deploying it on a Tomcat 9 external server (on premise), it was working properly until other employees made some changes and now it does not start when I deploy it on Tomcat. The thing I've noticed is that when I have the scope of the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency the application runs fine, but when i change the scope to provided it throws:

`Failed to parse configuration class [com.AEAplicacion.AEApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer`

I already tried every solution I've found, for example extending SpringBootServletInitializer in my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.AEAplicacion.*"})
@Import(WebConfig.class)
public class AEApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder){
        return builder.sources(AEApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("--- ingresa a: AEApplication");
        SpringApplication.run(AEApplication.class, args);
    }


  
}
```

Setting the scoped to provided on my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The logs of the tomcat server show this:

`24-Jan-2024 11:17:19.432 INFORMACI├ôN [Catalina-utility-1]  org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. .`

`24-Jan-2024 11:17:19.524 INFORMACI├ôN [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\AEApplication-1.0.0-IALABS.war] has finished in [55.419] ms`

But the application doesn't get started and when i try to access the application it only shows a 404 error

Comment: Hi. Why are you using "@Import(WebConfig.class)"? Are you defining your controller/view mapping in that file? If so, its not needed in the more recent versions of spring-boot.